# How to write test case for JSON getting form factory in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to write the test cass for the factory which is returing a JSON response.

But I am getting the error:

**Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=serviceProvider%20%3C-%20service
    at Error (native)**

Here is my code:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('uspDeviceService',[]).factory('getDevice', GetDevice);
    GetDevice.$inject = ['$http'];
    function GetDevice($http) {
            getDeviceList = function() {
                return $http.get("static/test-json/devices/device-list.json");
            }
        return {
            getDeviceList: getDeviceList
        }
    }
}());
```

***Code for Test case:***

```
describe('Get Product test', function() {

    beforeEach(module('uspDeviceService'));
    var service, httpBackend, getDevice ;
    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            //Injecting $http dependencies
            httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            service = $injector.get('service');
            getDevice = $injector.get('getDevice');
        })
    });
    console.log('Injection Dependencies is done');

    describe('get Device List', function () {
        it("should return a list of devices", inject(function () {
            httpBackend.expectGET("static/test-json/devices/device-list.json").respond("Response found!");

            httpBackend.flush();
        }))
    })

});
```

I am new to Angular Unit testing, can anyone please help me, where I am going wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Two things that jump out at me:

- Your `angular.module` declaration is *defining* a module, not *getting* the module.  I would encourage you to split that up so that it's a fair bit more clear what your intent is.

  ```
  angular.module('uspDeviceService', []);
  angular.module('uspDeviceService').factory('getDevice', GetDevice);
  ```

  It likely works as-is, but clarity is important.
- What is...`service`?  It's not defined anywhere in your code, and Angular can't find it either, hence the error message.  You may be looking to get `getDevice` instead.  Also, name your test variable with respect to what it actually is, so you don't confuse yourself.

  ```
  // defined above
  var getDevice;

  // while injecting
  getDevice = $injector.get('getDevice');
  ```

Comment: Ok I got it and then how to test whether JSON is coming or not?

Comment: @AnitaMehta:  Since this is a unit test, you would want to assume that JSON is always coming back accurately.  If you wanted to test the actual, live endpoint, then two words of caution:  since it's from a third party it will be brittle, and those sorts of tests are best left to an end-to-end test.

Comment: I just want to check whether data is coming back form factory, that's all

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have an angularjs controller myController defined in myModule. The controller do some action when the api call is success and shows a flash message when api returns success = false. The your controller code would be something like

```
angular.module('myModule')

.controller( 'myController', function ( $scope,flashService, Api ) {


   Api.get_list().$promise.then(function(data){
     if(data.success) {
       $scope.data = data.response
     }
     else{
       flashService.createFlash(data.message, "danger");
     }
  });

});
```

Now to test both success = true and success = false we

```
describe('myController', function(){

  var $rootScope, $httpBackend, controller, flashService;

  var apilink = 'http://apilink';

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_,_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _flashService_) {

    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    flashService = _flashService_;
    controller =  _$controller_("myController", {$scope: $rootScope});

  }));

 it('init $scope.data when success = true', function(){
   $httpBackend.whenGET(apilink)
   .respond(
    {
     success: true,
     response: {}

    });

    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect($rootScope.data).toBeDefined();
 });

 it('show flash when api request failure', function(){

  spyOn(flashService, 'createFlash');

  $httpBackend.whenGET(apilink)
 .respond(
  {
    success: false
  });

  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(flashService.createFlash).toHaveBeenCalled();

 });


});
```

You are always going to mock the response because here we are testing the javascript code behaviour and we are not concerned with the Api. You can see when success the data is initialized and when success is false createFlash is called.

As far as test for factory is concerned you can do

```
 describe('Get Product test', function() {

    beforeEach(module('uspDeviceService'));
    var service, httpBackend, getDevice ;
    beforeEach(function () {
       inject(function ($injector) {
         httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
         service = $injector.get('service');
         getDevice = $injector.get('getDevice');
       });
    });

   describe('get Device List', function () {
     it("should return a list of devices", inject(function () {

       httpBackend.expectGET("static/test-json/devices/device-  list.json").respond("Response found!");
       var result = getDevice.getDeviceList();
       httpBackend.flush();
       expect(result).toEqual('Response found!');

    }));
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but here I am trying to test factory individual just for testing purpose.Can you please tell whatever I am writing in factory, can I test by comparing the object inside the JSON response.

Comment: Added test for factory

Comment: Now I am geting this error :  Expected Object({ $$state: Object({ status: 1, value: Object({ data: 'Response found!', status: 200, headers: Function, config: Object({ metho
amSerializer: Function, url: 'static/test-json/devices/device-list.json', headers: Object({ Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*' }) }),
e found!'.

Comment: you can change expect(result).toEqual('Response found!') according to your expected output. I just added it as an example. you can do something like expect(result.$$state.value.data).toEqual('Response found!');

Comment: I am just trying to check but I am getting undefined, when I an trying like this.var result = getDevice.getDeviceList();
               console.log(result.status); I have status in my json file.